# C# List all processes that use your web camera at the moment

Tags: c#, windows, .net-6.0, webcam

I need to log information about any processes that starts to use a web camera.
I know there is a way to look it up in a registry by key:

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam\NonPackaged`

But I don`t know if this method is trustworthy: what if user will not have Capability Access Manager service running, or he uses any software to bypass it.

Is there any low level way to get all web camera sessions with processes specified?

Comment: Do you develop UWP app ?

Comment: No, just a .NET project